# what is the definition of the parameter 'verbose' in scikit learn kmeans clustering

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

Here is the kmeans algorithm class from scikit learn.

```
class sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, tol=0.0001, precompute_distances=True, verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, n_jobs=1)¶
```

Interested to know what 'verbose' means and in the output, it show inertia values, also not sure what that means. They did not explain in the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verbose means that it will output messages which could be useful for debugging and for understanding how the training is doing.

The inertia is the sum of the squared distance for each point to it's closest centroid, i.e., its assigned cluster. You can find more info about it [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means).